# adding a slash "/" on the end of my website URL causes Errors

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

Adding a "\" on the end of my website URL creates an error:

this one runs fine:

```
 test.com/index.aspx
```

But this one fails:

```
test.com/index.aspx/880
```

chrome debugging says "Failed to load resource.....jquery-2.1.4.min.js"

this is how it is referenced:

```
 <script src="/Scripts/jquery-2.1.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: You're using a relative path so when the URL changes so does the relative path. The relative doesn't change even when it should in your case so it can't find jQuery

Comment: is there a way to make it fixed? i'd prefer not to use the full website URL

Comment: Well, that's the purpose of absolute paths that include the whole url, to be fixed.

Answer (score 0):

```
test.com/index.aspx/880
```

does not look like a valid URL. Is `880` a parameter? Then `index.aspx?q=880`

Comment: This should be a comment. Does not answer the question and raises another one.

Comment: but stack overflow uses it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37903830/adding-a-slash-on-the-end

Comment: @Frank, to achieve same with asp.net webform you need to look into URL rewritting. MVC can be another option.

Comment: @AndrewL, is does not raise question but does answer as well. read again carefully.

Comment: If `test.com/index.aspx/880` does not exist then what page is trying to load jquery.js?

Comment: Oops..Thanks nnnnn for pointing that out ... that should cause 404, I amended answer and vote up for you

Answer (score 0):

The error "Failed to load resource.....jquery-2.1.4.min.js" was not a problem with referencing the jquery JavaScript but a problem with my ajax calls swapping them out from:

```
url: "index.aspx/AddPoint"
```

to

```
url: "/index.aspx/AddPoint"
```

fixed it

P.s. if anyone has similar problems don't forget to reference your JavaScript like this:

```
 <script src="/Scripts/jquery-2.1.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

and not like the more commonly used way:

```
 <script src="../Scripts/jquery-2.1.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```